# How do I edit an illustrator script on a mac. Script editor wont' work

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting

I'm new to scripts.  I want to use the Script Editor that comes with my mac, but I can't seem to make it work.  For example, I found the simplest possible Hello World java script on the internet, and  I copied it into Script editor, and nothing works:  [image]

As well, in the Adobe Illustator application folder, there are sample scripts, and Script Editor won't open them, as seen here they are grayed out:

[image]

which is really strange because I can run these scripts in Illustrator.

I can run these scripts but I can't edit them.

Obviously, the apple script editor doesn't like .jsx files, but I can't find any documentation on the internet that mentions this.

ps. I did try to change the preferences of the editor to java script, as seen below.
[image]

but it doesn't help.

pss. I just download an app from the applestore called BBBEdit, and it won't open .jsx files either, see below
[image]

Why is it so difficult to edit these files?  I'm pretty good at picking up programming languages, but if I can't get a simple Hello World to function, then I'm missing something very fundamental.

thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131862/discussion-on-question-by-chris-how-do-i-edit-an-illustrator-script-on-a-mac-s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not supposed to work. Script needs to be run by Adobe application not OS. Pretty normal stuff, compare this to wanting to open file in textEdit versus InDesign. Who runs something is just as important as what it is.

If you want to use the script editor then you should use applescript API of adobe instead. But then it wouldnt be portable and you would have less resources.